# Transferring OSX and Data by putting an SSD I had in my 2012 Macbook into my new 2015 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mojave, ssd, catalina

As the title says, I have an old SSD that I installed in my 2012 Macbook Pro with all of my files on it and was running Mojave. I now got a 2015 mac, which is running catalina. What's the best way to install my old SSD into this macbook (the old SSD is an upgrade from what's currently in the 2015 model I have) and have the OSX and data transfer safely?

Comment: I'm not convinced that a 2015 MBP can take an SSD module from a 2012 MBP: they use different connectors. The 2012 Macs uses 7+17 pin blade, and the 2015 use the 12+16 pin blade.
If you just want to transfer the data and apps, then use the Migration Assistant with the 2012 in Target Disk Mode. Or restore stuff from your backup.

Comment: If the hardware does fit, then you can jut swap the SSD in, with all the data on it.